# Specify in rpm spec to not remove unmodified files and directories during uninstall

Tags: rpm, configuration-files, uninstallation

I would like to know how to specify in rpm spec that some files and directories must not be removed during uninstall even if there are not been modified?

I have some directories that contain configuration files. These files are installed with rpm -ivh. Some of installed files are not always modified and should not be remove at uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a native way to do it. I don't see why you would if they were unmodified; the end user can always `rpm2cpio` or re-install if they wanted the originals.

However, to do it, you could do something like package all the files into `/etc/yourapp/orig/` and then in your `%post` do something like `cp /etc/yourapp/orig/*.conf /etc/yourapp`. You'd have to do more advanced stuff to keep it from stomping on previously installed and modified config files, but it's a hackish idea to run with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is actually the way I have chosen to do it.

Comment: Then please upvote and/or check the checkbox to make it an "accepted answer."